# Passing arguments in a nested For Range loop in Python 2.5

Tags: python

I'm just learning Python and am trying to figure out how to pass an argument in a 'for range' loop to a variable.  In the code below, I would like the 'months' variable to be the names of the months (Jan, Feb, etc).  Then I'm trying to get the user prompt for the 'sales' variable to read 'Enter the sales for Jan'.  Then with the next iteration, move to the next month - 'Enter the sales for Feb'

Thank you for any suggestions.

```
def main():
    number_of_years = input('Enter the number of years for which you would like to compile data: ')
    total_sales = 0.0
    total_months = number_of_years * 12

    for years in range(number_of_years):
        for months in range(1, 13):
            sales = input('Enter sales: ')
            total_sales += sales

    print ' '        
    print 'The number of months of data is: ', total_months
    print ' '
    print 'The total amount of sales is: ', total_sales 
    print ' '
    average = total_sales / total_months    # variable to average results
    print 'The average monthly sales is: ', average

main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Python's dict and list objects will take you far.

```
>>> months = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec".split()
>>> sales = {}
>>> for num, name in enumerate(months, 1):
    print "Sales for", name
    sales[num] = 14.99 # get the sales here
    print "Num:", num

Sales for Jan
Num: 1
Sales for Feb
Num: 2
Sales for Mar
Num: 3
Sales for Apr
Num: 4
... etc.

>>> for month, price in sales.items():
    print month, "::", price

1 :: 14.99
2 :: 14.99
... etc.

>>> ave = sum(sales.values()) / float(len(sales)) # average sales
```

Comment: calendar.month_name[1] == 'January', etc., which is sometimes handy, but not pedagogically useful so +1 for doing it manually.

Comment: Suggest `enumerate(months,1)`.

Comment: Why not use sales[name] directly?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is something that allows you to convert month numbers from 1-12 to month name abbreviations. While you *could* do that fairly easily with a list of month names as long as you remember to always subtract 1 from the month number before using it because lists are indexed from 0 not 1. Another alternative that doesn't require that would be to use a Python dictionary.

Using a dictionary, your program might look like something like this:

```
# construct dictionary
month_names = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec".split()
months = dict((i, month) for i, month in enumerate(month_names, 1))

def main():
    number_of_years = input('Enter the number of years for which '
                            'you would like to compile data: ')
    total_sales = 0.0
    total_months = number_of_years * 12

    for years in range(number_of_years):
        for month in range(1, 13):
            sales = input('Enter sales for %s: ' % months[month])
            total_sales += sales

    print
    print 'The number of months of data is: ', total_months
    print
    print 'The total amount of sales is: ', total_sales
    print
    average = total_sales / total_months    # variable to average results
    print 'The average monthly sales is: ', average

main()
```

In addition to adding the construction of the `months` dictionary, I modified your call to `input()` to use that variable so the user prompt displays the name of the month.

BTW, you might also want to change the statement that prints the average to:

`print 'The average monthly sales is: "%.2f"' % average`

So it only displays 2 digits after the decimal point (instead of many more).